# Minimal Permutation Representation Degree of a group: GAP implementation

Tags: gap

For a finite group $G$, let $\mu(G)$ be the least positive integer $n$ such that $G$ is embedded as a subgroup of the symmetric group on $n$ points. In other words, $\mu(G)$ is the minimal permutation representation degree of $G$.

> Note here that $\mu(G)$ is the minimum of $\sum_{i=1}^t |G:H_i|$ over
>   all sets of subgroups $H_1, H_2, \ldots, H_t$ such that
>   $\bigcap_{i=1}^t\mathrm{Core}_G(H_i) = 1$, which is equivalent to
>   $\mathrm{Core}_G(K) = 1$, $K = \bigcap_{i=1}^tH_i$.

My question concerns finding $\mu(G)$ with GAP. There is some functionality available to do this, which is, however, not guaranteed to succeed. Below is a naive routine of mine which makes use of this limited functionality of GAP:

```
mprd:=function(g)
 local iso,image,small;
  iso:=IsomorphismPermGroup(g);;
  image:=Image(iso);;
  small:=SmallerDegreePermutationRepresentation(image);;
   return NrMovedPoints(Image(small));;
end;;
```

Asking for `mprd(d8)`, where `d8:=DihedralGroup(8);;` returns a value of `8`, whereas the actual value is 4.

My question is twofold:

1. When is the above `mprd` routine guaranteed to succeed finding the correct value of $\mu(G)$? In other words, when is `SmallerDegreePermutationRepresentation` actually *smallest*?
2. What is the fastest way to find the true value of $\mu(G)$ with GAP using just the observation above that it is the minimum of $\sum_{i=1}^t |G:H_i|$ ?

To elaborate a little on the first question. An early paper of [Johnson](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373739) has theoretical arguments to find $\mu(G)$ for certain classes of groups (abelian groups, direct products of groups of coprime orders). Have these arguments been taken into account in the implementation of `SmallerDegreePermutationRepresentation`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Added 1/23:**
There now (GAP 4.12) are built-in functions `MinimalFaithfulPermutationDegree` and `MinimalFaithfulPermutationRepresentation` in GAP that guarantee to find the minimal degree. AH

---

`SmallerDegreePermutationRepresentation` aims to find, at limited cost, an isomorphic group in which subsequent calculations will be faster. It is purely a heuristic which, however, can have significant influence on the user experience. The typical case of use is that a prior calculation gave a group in a permutation representation that is far too large -- say you take $M_{12}$ as a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(M_{12})$ which would be double the degree, though absolute numbers are small in this example.

It of course uses some subgroups -- the point stabilizers -- but makes absolutely no attempt to prove minimality of the degree obtained. It also cares more to reduce 100000 to 5000 than to reduce 1017 to 1015, the latter being not really a practical difference.

So the only cases in which I reckon the degree would be minimal are ``obvious'' cases -- cyclic groups of prime power orders, or elementary abelian groups.

The heuristics in `SmallerDegreePermutationRepresentation` do not use the arguments of the paper you cite (or others) as in general the groups encountered will be unlikely to lie in these particular classes, respectively we do not want to test for these particular cases as we want to minimize the number of calculations in the larger degree permutation group.

If you really want the true value of $\mu$ in arbitrary cases, I suspect you cannot do better in general than to consider *all* possible collections of subgroups, ordered by sum of the degrees. For that you would have to calculate at least part of the subgroup lattice, though you could start iteratively with maximal subgroups, or factors in a subdirect product decomposition. (The next release of GAP will have a function `LowLayerSubgroup` that determines subgroups that are $k$-fold maximal for small $k$.) Doing this properly for arbitrary groups is on the level of a decent research article.

PS: If you are a glutton for punishment -- i.e willing to read in German -- you can find a textual description of an early version of the code underlying the routine in section V.2 of my thesis at [http://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/paper/prom.ps.gz](http://www.math.colostate.edu/%7Ehulpke/paper/prom.ps.gz) )

Comment: I wonder if it might be beneficial to determine first a "good" range for $\mu(G)$, i.e. $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a \leq \mu(G) \leq b$, where $b-a$ is "small". It is possible to find such bounds for $a,b$ "theoretically" (see MR1213975). Maybe it is then easier to pin down the exact value of $\mu(G)$.

Comment: @the_fox If you want to implement a separat function for $\mu$ (which would not be the goal of the `SmallerDegree...` function) then yes, having some bounds would help. However the bounds you cite are not very tight and require information that is too costly to compute for `SmallerDegree...`

Comment: It's not clear to me though: how might one iterate over all subgroups to get the minimum? Even a naive routine would be welcomed.

Comment: @the_fox You store minimal degrees for each factor and then iterate through subgroups, updating degrees of their cores. I have put a quick and dirty implementation at https://www.dropbox.com/s/9on2yj0fhxnzave/valuemue.g?dl=0    Let me know if it doesn't behave or you spot bugs.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate this very much!

Comment: I think your effort deserves a little more credit. I have started a bounty, and will reward your answer in 24 hours.

Comment: @the_fox That is very kind of you. I realized that others might want such a function as well and will put it (maybe name changes) in future GAP releases.

Comment: I would suggest that you put the link to Dropbox on the main body of your answer so as to be more visible (maybe someone will not look at the comments). Also, perhaps you can update your code to deal with easy cases. For example, if $G$ is abelian then $\mu(G)$ is the trace of $G$. If $G, H$ are nilpotent then $\mu(G \times H) = \mu(G) + \mu(H)$ and the same is true if $G, H$ have coprime orders. I will update my question to include some relevant bibliography.

Comment: By the way, the code contains at least one bug. Check $A_5 \times A_5$ to see this. Perhaps weird behaviour is exhibited only when direct products are involved.

Comment: Nope, I just checked that the correct value, which is 35, is returned for the direct product of the quaternion group of order 32 with the cyclic group of order 3. Maybe when insoluble groups are involved something goes wrong.

Comment: @the_fox Thanks for pointing this out -- there was a stupid error left that I just fixed. If you encounter other problems, please email me directly, as I think the comments section is not a god place for this.

Comment: @ahulpke Can you share the GAP code (dropbox link) again ? Or please mention where can I find that code ? Thank you.

Comment: @Jins It is now (release 4.12) built into GAP. Functions `MinimalFaithfulPermutationDegree` and `MinimalFaithfulPermutationRepresentation`.