# How to determine the smallest $\ m\ $ with $\ G\le S_m\ $?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $\ G\ $ be a finite group with $\ |G|=n\ $

Caley's theorem states that $\ G\ $ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group $\ S_n\ $

However, in many cases, the smallest positive integer $\ m\ $, such that $\ G\ $ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\ S_m\ $ is smaller than $\ n\ $.

> How can I determine $\ m\ $ , if I do not have access to GAP ?

Is there some applet or online calculator that can do this ? Or can $\ m\ $ be calculated by knowing specific properties of $\ G \ $ ?

Comment: I believe this is a rather hard problem in general. Perhaps [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4122) may be of some use.

Comment: Also https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373739.

Comment: @Sunyata If I could do this for any group upto, lets say, order $100$ , I would already be content.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3362386/732532) answer may also be helpful.

Comment: There's no way you can do this without using a computer. See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610535/minimal-permutation-representation-degree-of-a-group-gap-implementation)

Comment: @the_fox I found two online calculators : "wims permutation groups" and "magma-online-calculator" which are helpful in special cases. Do you know how to use them for more complicated groups ?

Comment: I am only familiar with GAP, unfortunately. GAP has the capacity to do this calculation, but be a little wary as there was a bug reported. I am not sure if it has since been fixed.

Comment: This has been asked a bunch of times, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36846/minimal-embedding-of-a-group-into-the-group-s-n